# MSR server deplyment error in time series analysis deployment using R programming on azure batch processing

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on a time series analysis application using R programming and it is working fine on my local machine and now the problem started with the deployment procedure of R program code to azure cognitive services.

As per my research I found that under batch processing we can implement MSR server creation and I am unable to find the document which was created.

> Error: Could not index document because some of the document's data was not valid

I was expecting to create MSRdeploy procedure and received this error.

Any error rectification mechanisms are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Error: Could not index document because some of the document's data was not valid**

This could be the error occurred because of the data type of the fields extracted using the indexer is not compatible with the model. The indexer of the corresponding model and the target model might be different.
There is also another chance there to get error while extracting the JSON entry with the string value.

As there is error in deployment, check with the flow of deployment using MSRdeploy.

Follow the below steps to perform the MSRdeploy.

- R programming supporting deployment models on azure platform are different in style. We can deploy using the following services:
  o   Data science virtual machine
  o   ML services with HDInsight
  o   Azure Databricks
  o   Azure Machine learning
  o   Azure batch
  o   Azure SQL managed instance.
  **Note:** **MSRDeploy** is available in **Azure Databricks** and not available in **batch processing**.
  Considering that the operation is based on **MSRdeploy**, the following procedure will help to re-check the work on the same deployment.

1. Go to [portal.azure.com](https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fms.portal.azure.com%2Fsignin%2Findex%2F&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F%2Fuser_impersonation%20openid%20email%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3Dy2lmknCd6wDJ1bzbxII_AEVjwYSq1BpYJVhV4BGDelLaMfTP_d4lEF-M5E5lsQ6nmyPtCLypTPLSxXLk3AFwQpcMmgQPjAQMWkS1vb8baJ49UJHpmCprxzB-zc5fFcEBH_UWl6_puK82qPPTyKv01Q64BbXM1aTefEvAEsLqcihPbzbVbHun8Z5ZrQZSnqbNSejYSZJucybaPoFoCa648FR9yaVZLyRhjfU477b9ThPdwnTafJu7uFHwmQ9mfvP-QF_0Ls5JWikZx1dWVTU6W2K81z1hYjpdqrLSC_hXc9ODlqXUgR3LNSuwypiS_1ZD_XPO2-0heD7-PwQfdotbye7WWUWGaiM-Uk4n0cEuPG5cm6SzCYeEdOhiAknJyRkpBSdotZ2B4y-89SJhRM4eorOdP4iWwzCq6xlI6mvkRRbZgvOCYfl3GhiMa-2vPB2P9hP7Una0dYoFq4OixjrbGrt-2Z4L52Y2Kmc_wAk2PWLrZuBV7m7e4FlGhQc_rngBlTPDnEdPVfe9-UVi-GUPCQ&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637956386589134684.YzBlMTBiNDYtZGQ5ZS00MWY3LTkyMjEtNTlkNGJiNDA4NTgwNjU5MTBhZTYtMDUxOS00MmE0LWExNjAtM2UwMmIzNDI4MjU3&client_id=c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c&site_id=501430&client-request-id=1a8dffd7-699a-4385-a900-29068e0d473d&x-client-SKU=ID_NET472&x-client-ver=6.16.0.0&sso_nonce=O.eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OnJ0OmNoYWxsZW5nZSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY2MDA0MTg1OSwibmJmIjoxNjYwMDQxODU5LCJleHAiOjE2NjAwNDIxNTl9.H3xvguX4voBPGrpeO7MQgi3akxFwg2QTqtP421fIGqu5hsL8mfsWf-PSJaX83fE36aO2VtigjHq7_QDPP0Hrrs_dcDUerrUrZQYEjMu2dO9D2LuzdC8IUHWZt8Lp0vB3b1LI2IH-O4MYW044GHvJtCiZ8FBuBFRjrWnBJQCBwHcC2zgarGM_3C66l-xx7-104ZYMc1J-tdfodWrAE8DB9gJvsoaAHO1xMgh7aK_jWMocARy0ep14f4tULYTMEn7BRVeeLKZT0-aOC03zibPD_q4n0QpUPmAI5et4JYLgZRzuIla5taLzNabvynwdlXehP0c7mLTtkqrK-9VErRwziA&mscrid=1a8dffd7-699a-4385-a900-29068e0d473d)
2. Under the services, Search for **r server**
3. Select the **Ubuntu** version and give a name
4. Login with Virtual Machine and get the path of R executable
5. **MSR** is also considered as **Revo64**
6. Check with the configuration

**alias rserver='/usr/local/bin/Revo64-9.0'**

```
alias radmin='sudo /usr/local/bin/dotnet/usr/lib64/microsoft-deployr/9.0.1/Microsoft.DeployR.Utils.AdminUtil/Microsoft.DeployR.Utils.AdminUtil.dll'
```

7. Using “radmin” setup the MSR deploy
8. For reference, consider checking the following document. [link](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/03/running-your-r-code-azure.html)

Credit: [Revolution Analytics](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/03/running-your-r-code-azure.html)

Comment: Thanks for showing me where I am doing wrong. It worked for me using data bricks.